Intermittent Audio Crackling/Clicking Every 5-30 Seconds on High-End Setup
I'm encountering a frustrating audio issue on my Microsoft Surface Laptop Studio 2, and I'm hoping someone here can help. The specs of my laptop are as follows:

CPU: i7 13700H @ 2.9GHz
RAM: 64 GB @ 5200 MT/s
GPU: RTX 4060 Laptop
Storage: 1TB SSD
OS: Windows 11 Home

Every 5-30 seconds, I hear a crackling or clicking sound during audio playback. As a music producer, I'm familiar with CPU overload causing similar issues, but this is different. It's just a single click rather than multiple clicks or continuous distortion. However the Clicking Sound By itself is kind of similar to CPU overload but as i said its just one click and not continuous. In all Situations ive expirienced this Clicking my Laptop was not on full load or even close (pretty hard with this setup)
What I've Tried:

Driver Reinstallation: Completely reinstalled all audio drivers.
Different Applications: Tested across various applications; the issue persists.
Audio Settings Adjustment: Changed audio enhancements, bit rate, and sample rate.
External Audio Interface: Used a Focusrite Scarlett 2i2, but the problem remained.
Bluetooth Headphones: The issue is almost non-existent here, with only one click in 30 minutes that coincided with a Windows notification sound.
Observations:

The clicking isn't consistent or reproducible. Driver re-installation occasionally offers temporary relief, but the problem resurfaces.
The issue is more prevalent with wired audio devices (internal speakers, wired headphones, external audio interfaces).
The cracking happens on multiple locations and with multiple devices. Also i put my phone away and other devices. This still occurs
Additional Information:
My Bluetooth headphones have almost no issues, which makes me think it might be related to the wired audio processing. The laptop's performance and temperatures are normal during these occurrences.
I'm at a loss for what else to try. Has anyone experienced similar issues or have any suggestions on what might be causing this?

If you take ONLY THE TABLET and wired audio device that has these issues to an entirely different location, as in, not just another room, but another building, another place, etc, do you have the same symptoms? Clicking or crackling could be interference from an external source, so test in a different location. It is possible the interference could be from something else you carry, so turn your phone off, leave behind or fully turn off any electric or electronic devices you'd normally carry with you to fully isolate the cause.

this sounds like DPC latency and also sounds like the source might be something other than the audio chain itself. Some people suggest Nvidia drivers (some of the telemetry stuff for example) can cause this in audio production. If the SSD is over 70 or 80% full, I have heard that the latency can crank up pretty high. Check your power plan and try setting it to "fans first/then throttle" for heat management. Try disabling wifi and bluetooth as a test.  I think focusrite has a dpc latency FAQ on their site with some suggestions.

Check if it's interference from one or more cell phones. When not in continual use, cell phones send a signal to find towers and check for inbound call every few seconds. That is a fairly strong signal, a few watts to connect to a distant tower, and can be picked up on audio lines.
